# Any explanation for this peculiar React unique key prop warning using React.cloneElement?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-props

I have a component `List` which accepts as children:

```
type Props = {
   children: React.ReactElement[]
}
```

In my main component I have:

```
return <List>
  <div .../>
  <div .../>
<List/>
```

and in `List` component:

when I do

```
render() {
        return <div ...>
            {
                this.props.children.map((c, i) => {
                    return React.cloneElement(c, {key: i});
                })
            }
        </div>;
```

everything works fine, but when I wrap `React.cloneElement` inside `<></>`, React throws the unique prop key warning.

```
return <>
 {React.cloneElement(c, {key: i})}
</>
```

Why is that ?

Comment: key must be unique between its sibling so if you have them into a div that's work fine. if you return a fragment you have to be sure you aren't using those same keys anywhere else in the "upper level" aswell. hope this makes sense

Comment: If it's in a fragment then the key should be on the fragment rather than on the element.